# I get the following JS code: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently testing some javascript snow for a client, and have a working version on codepen (http://codepen.io/pirrera/pen/qEOqLg).

Now, I implemented that in a [site](http://pirrera.ch/swiss/) (just plain bootstrap including the JS from codepen), but I get an error saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null

I don't know why this isn't working on my site, but it is working on codepen? :(

Here's the JS code:

```
(function () {

var COUNT = 300;
var masthead = document.querySelector('.sky');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = masthead.clientWidth;
var height = masthead.clientHeight;
var i = 0;
var active = false;
```

<-snip-> full code [here](http://codepen.io/pirrera/pen/qEOqLg)

Comment: Don't see any problem from the question. Maybe you should check if your site has set the classname `sky`, otherwise `document.querySelector('.sky')` will be `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following part of the code returns null, this is why you cannot access the property `clientWidth` of it.

```
document.querySelector('.sky')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Set the id of  'sky' to 'sky'
2. use `document.getElementById('sky').clientWidth;`

---

## Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing class="sky" on your body.

your body tag should look like this:
`<body data-twttr-rendered="true" class="sky">`

or change query selector in js to:
`var masthead = document.querySelector('body');`

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot that :/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set classname `sky` to your `<body>` tag. Or maybe you can use `var masthead = document.querySelector('body');` instead.